# Что нужно, и на чем сделать надежный чат, обмен сообщениями?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, node.js, laravel

Добрый вечер всем !

Нужна помощь от профи )) Мне необходимо реализовать проект на laravel (типа корпоративная соц-сеть). В принципе ничего сложного нет, **кроме чатов, обмена сообщениями и моментальных оповещений!**

Даже не знаю как и какими средствами это реализовывается! Сейчас ищу инфу - пока все сводится к `node.js` или лучше использовать сокеты с `php` библиотек?! **Что нужно применить чтобы сделать надежный, синхронный и быстрый обмен сообщениями ??**

Буду рад любому отзыву по-теме !! Спасибо)

Comment: что для вас значит надежный?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ну как минимум, что б пару сотен людей могли спокойно переписываться и не было никаких проблем с перебоями или падениями сервера !

Comment: websockets is all you need

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, был такой вариант )) Но опыта на js нет и не знаю сколько нужно опыта для этого

Comment: думаю, что с парой сотен человек проблем не будет и на php, и node. так что выбирайте, что знаете.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, спасибо за совет )) А если намного больше людей, что выбирать в приоритете ?

Comment: @Maybe_V на много -  это на сколько?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, намного ) примерно до 2/3 тысячи или даже больше (но это я сильно преувеличиваю )

Comment: думаю и это не станет проблемой - просто возьмете сервер по мощнее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо )